# du and du -h give different results, and neither match ls -lh

Tags: files, ls, disk-usage

I can paste a screenshot if preferred, but here is what I typed:

```
me@server:~/dutest/test2$ du
12  .
me@server:~/dutest/test2$ du -h
12K .
me@server:~/dutest/test2$ du -b
4243    .
me@server:~/dutest/test2$ ls -alh
total 16K
drwxrwxr-x 2 me me 4.0K Jul  8 23:14 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 me me 4.0K Jul  8 23:03 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me    2 Jul  8 23:03 b.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me  145 Jul  8 23:09 test.php
me@server:~/dutest/test2$
```

As you can see, `du` says it's 12 (EDIT: kilo)bytes, `du -h` says it's 12 kilobytes, (EDIT) and `du -b` says it's 4243 bytes. `ls -lh` says total 16K at the top, but I also see there are just 147 bytes worth of files.

Why are they all so different and which is correct? If I was looping through the files one by one, adding the filesize for the file to a counter, how would I calculate the percentage complete I am at if I only know the current total filesize looped through, and the full total from `du`? For example, If I had processed test.php but not b.txt, my counter would be at 145 bytes, and I know the total from `du` is 4243. I know that the "real" total is 147, so I am 98.6% done, but how do I get there from only knowing the 4243 total from `du`?

For reference I am on Ubuntu 22 here, running in a virtual machine.

Thanks!

Comment: `du` and `du -h` actually match - 12 means 12k

Comment: Aha, thanks. That helps with that! `du -b` gives me the total bytes as 4243, I'll edit the post to add that

Comment: Looks like your block size is 4k, and you have the directory plus two files each occupying a block, so a total of 12k, in line with what du says. `ls` also apparently counting the parent directory's hard link (`..`) in the total, which I guess is understandable